# How do I retwist Christmas lights?

Tags: lighting

[image: Image of an untwisted section]

I have a set of Christmas lights in trying to untangle. One of the issues I'm facing is that, in some places, the wires have come untwisted, which makes them more prone to tangle. Is there any way to fix that? A trick to weaving them back together?

The bit above is actually one of the areas where they aren't as bad, but in a few places, there's a few inches of basically three separate wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a spool to store them

They make a wide variety of wire caddies and spools intended for spooling up extension cords.  My "go to" is about 18" long, flat, and looks like this:

```
   ------+--------------------------+------
         |                          |
   ------+--------------------------+------
                  \------/
```

That thing being a handle.  You attach one end (they give a little hook for that and spool up the wires.  That's great for storage and easy unfurling.

However, to re-twist, the spool is especially essential. As you're spooling up the wire, when you hit an untwisted area, stop short of it.  Rotate the whole spool.  That lets you add twist to the wires as needed.

Comment: That indeed worked. I didn't know if there was a trick to it, but it turned out the only trick was getting my wife to hold one end, and then the other, while I twisted and then fed it onto the reel.

Comment: @SeanDuggan  And if you store them in an attic, the summer heat will help mold the twist in the wires.